# Problemas con la codificación del Botón Editar (Está incompleto o talvez falta corregir)

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy creando una aplicación en Android Studio, se trata de una agenda con SQLite. Si bien la aplicación se logra ejecutar pero no funciona el botón "Editar".[![DIRECTORIO DE MI PROYECTO][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3BSl.png
ESTOS SON LOS CÓDIGOS:

Handler_Sqlite.java:

```
package com.example.david.db_contactos.database;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    public class Handler_Sqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {
    public static final String _ID="_id";
    public static final String NOMBRE="NOMBRE";
    public static final String DIRECCION="DIRECCION";
    public static final String CORREO="CORREO";
    public static final String TELEFONO="TELEFONO";
    public Handler_Sqlite(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version){
        super(context,name,factory,version);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE contactos(" + _ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NOMBRE TEXT, DIRECCION TEXT,CORREO TEXT, TELEFONO TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contactos");
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void insertarReg(String nom,String dir,String cor,String tel){
        ContentValues valores=new ContentValues();
        valores.put("NOMBRE",nom);
        valores.put("DIRECCION",dir);
        valores.put("CORREO",cor);
        valores.put("TELEFONO",tel);
        this.getWritableDatabase().insert("contactos",null,valores);
        }
    public void  EliminarReg(int cod){
        this.getWritableDatabase().delete("contactos",_ID+"="+cod,null);
        }
    public void abrir(){
        this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
       public void cerrar(){
        this.close();
    }
    public Cursor listaContactos(){
        Cursor
                micursor=this.getReadableDatabase().query("contactos",new String[]{_ID,NOMBRE,DIRECCION,CORREO,TELEFONO},null,null,null,null,null);
        if(micursor!=null){
            micursor.moveToFirst();
            System.out.println("resultado");
            System.out.println(micursor.getCount());
        }else {
            System.out.println("nancy");
        }
        return micursor;
    }
    public Cursor ListarxNombre(String inputText) throws SQLException{
        Cursor mCursor=null;
        if(inputText==null || inputText.length()==0){
            mCursor=this.getReadableDatabase().query("contactos",new String[]{_ID,NOMBRE,DIRECCION,CORREO,TELEFONO},null,null,null,null,null);
        }else {
            mCursor=this.getReadableDatabase().query("contactos",new String[]{_ID,NOMBRE,DIRECCION,CORREO,TELEFONO},NOMBRE+" like '%"+inputText+"%'",null,null,null,null);
        }
        if (mCursor!=null){
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

  public Cursor ListarxCod(int cod) {

        Cursor
                micursor=this.getReadableDatabase().query("contactos",new String[]{_ID,NOMBRE,DIRECCION,CORREO,TELEFONO},null,null,null,null,null);

        if(micursor!=null){
           micursor.moveToFirst();
           System.out.println("resultado");
           System.out.println(micursor.getCount());

        }else {
           System.out.println("nancy");
        }
        return micursor;
    }
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.david.db_contactos;
import com.example.david.db_contactos.database.Handler_Sqlite;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Handler_Sqlite helper=new Handler_Sqlite(this,"Bd1",null,1);
        //BOTON GRABAR
        Button btngrabar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btngrabar);
        btngrabar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                TextView nom=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtnom);
                TextView dir=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdir);
                TextView correo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcorreo);
                TextView tel=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txttel);
                String nom2=String.valueOf(nom.getText());
                String dir2=String .valueOf(dir.getText());
                String cor2=String.valueOf(correo.getText());
                String tel2=String .valueOf(tel.getText());
                helper.abrir();
                helper.insertarReg(nom2,dir2,cor2,tel2);
                helper.cerrar();
                nom.setText("");
                dir.setText("");
                correo.setText("");
                tel.setText("");
                nom.findFocus();
                Toast msg=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se grabó a "+nom2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                msg.show();
            }
        });
        //BOTON MOSTRAR
        Button btnmostrar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnmostrar);
        btnmostrar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity_listado.class);
                //estas sentencia indica que la actividad principal espera un resutado
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        //BOTON ELIMINAR
            Button btneliminar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btneliminar);
        btneliminar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity_Eliminar.class);
                //Esta sentencia indica que la actividad principal espera un resultado
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        //BOTON EDITAR
        Button btneditar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btneditar);
        btneditar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity_listado.class);
                //estas sentencia indica que la actividad principal espera un resutado
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

MainActivity_Eliminar.java:

```
package com.example.david.db_contactos;

import com.example.david.db_contactos.database.Handler_Sqlite;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity_Eliminar extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eliminar);
        final Handler_Sqlite helper=new Handler_Sqlite(this,"Bd1",null,1);
        Button btneliminar2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.botoneliminar2);
        btneliminar2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView cod = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtcodeliminar);
                int cod2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cod.getText()));
                helper.abrir();
                helper.EliminarReg(cod2);
                helper.cerrar();
                cod.setText("");
                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Se Eliminó el Registro " + cod2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                msg.show();
            }
            });

    }
}
```

MainActivity_Editar.java:

```
package com.example.david.db_contactos;
import com.example.david.db_contactos.database.Handler_Sqlite;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
    public class MainActivity_Editar extends Activity {
//declaramos la variable que almacenara el codigo enviado
    String codrecuperado="";
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editar);
        //instanciamos la base de datos
        final Handler_Sqlite helper=new Handler_Sqlite(this,"Bd1",null,1);
        //recuperamos el valor enviado
        Bundle recupera=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(recupera!=null){
            codrecuperado=recupera.getString("clave");
        }
        //declaramos todos los textbox
        TextView cod3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcod3);
        TextView nom3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtnom3);
        TextView dir3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdir3);
        TextView cor3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcor3);
        TextView tel3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txttel3);
        cod3.setText(codrecuperado);
        int codenviado=Integer.parseInt(codrecuperado.toString());
        Cursor cursor=helper.ListarxCod(codenviado);               nom3.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.NOMBRE)));            dir3.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.DIRECCION)));            cor3.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.CORREO)));            tel3.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.TELEFONO)));
    }
}
```

MainActivity_lista.java:

```
package com.example.david.db_contactos;
import com.example.david.db_contactos.database.Handler_Sqlite;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Helpers;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FilterQueryProvider;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
 public class MainActivity_listado extends Activity {
   //instanciamos la base de datos
    final Handler_Sqlite helper=new Handler_Sqlite(this,"Bd1",null,1);
  //creamos un cursos q permite recorrer y recuperar los registros
  SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
  //creamos un objeto de tipo listview
    ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listado_principal);
        //llamamos a la funcion cargar contactos creada mas abajo
        cargarContactos();
        //creamos el objeto de tipo edittext y lo referenciamos a la caja de texto
        EditText texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtcontacto);
        //creamos un evento para la caja de texto
        texto.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            //cuando cambie el texto
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //Le agregamos la condicion de busqueda
                dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
                //antes de que cambie el texto
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
                //despues de que cambie el texto
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        //aplicamos un criterio de búsqueda
        //este metodo genera una especie de consulta con un criterio de consulta
        //el metodo filter obliga a disparar este metodo
        dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            @Override
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return helper.ListarxNombre(constraint.toString());
            }
        });
        //Activamos el clic del listado para que capture el codigo y lo envie al otro layout
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            //public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                //recuperamos el item que esta en tal posicion
                Cursor xcursor = (Cursor) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //este metodo hace que recupere este valor o devuelve una excepcion
                String cod = xcursor.getString(xcursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cod,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Ahora enviamos el valor capturado a mainactivity_editar
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity_Editar.class);
                i.putExtra("clave", cod);
                //Estas sentencias indica que la actividad principal espera un resultado
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    private void cargarContactos(){
        //helper.abrir();
        try {
        Cursor cursor=helper.listaContactos();
        //colocamos el nombre de las columnas que va a ir al listview
        //el nombre de las columnas estan en countriesdbadapter
        String[] columnas={Handler_Sqlite._ID,Handler_Sqlite.NOMBRE,Handler_Sqlite.DIRECCION, Handler_Sqlite.CORREO,Handler_Sqlite.TELEFONO};
        //COLOCAMOS LOS VALORES DE CADA COLUMNA DONDE SE VAN A PINTAR
            int[]donde={R.id.txtcod,R.id.txtnom2,R.id.txtdireccion2,R.id.txtcorreo2,R.id.txttelefono2};
            //ahora seleccionamos el adaptador que vamos a utilizar para mostrar los valores
            dataAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.listado,cursor,columnas,donde);
            lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
                    }}
```

MainActivity_listado_principal.java:

```
package com.example.david.db_contactos
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
     public class MainActivity_listado_principal extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.listado_principal);
        }
    }
```

activity_editar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Editar Contacto" />
       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Codigo" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtcod3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName">
                <requestFocus/>
            </EditText>
                    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nombre"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtnom3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Direccion"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtdir3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Correo" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtcor3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Telefono" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txttel3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"/>
             </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btneditar2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Editar Datos"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Contactos"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
   </LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/txtcod"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nombre: "/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtnom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName">
        <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
      </TableRow>

  <TableRow
      android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txtnom2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Direccion: " />
      <EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtdir"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textPersonName" />
  </TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtdireccion2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Correo: "/>
     <EditText
     android:id="@+id/txtcorreo"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:ems="10"
         android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtcorreo2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Telefono: "  />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txttel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btngrabar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Grabar Contacto" />
  <TableRow
      android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnmostrar"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Mostrar Contactos" />
    </TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btneliminar"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Eliminar"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btneditar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Editar" />
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

listado_principal.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Listado de Contactos"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtcontacto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_eliminar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ingrese Codigo a Eliminar:"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtcodeliminar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/botoneliminar2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Eliminar Registro" />
</LinearLayout>
```

listado.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
    <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Codigo:" />    
                <!--LIMITADO en caracteres para poner código completo de esta parte :/-->
```